# Why can I not speed up crawling with multithreading in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

Down below you see a blue print of my crawler. I thought I could speed it up with multithreading but I can't. Often times when I load a page the webserver is slow and then it would be nice to crawl another webpage that loads faster with multithreading. But it isn't faster. Why?

```
def start_it():
    while(True):
        get_urls()

def get_urls():
   response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   page_source = str(response.read())

pool = ThreadPool(10)

pool.map(start_it())
```

Ok I tested if the threads run parallel and they are not :/ What am I doing wrong?

```
def start_it():

    x = random.random()
    while(True):
        get_urls(x)

def get_urls(x):
    print(x)

pool = ThreadPool(10)

pool.map(start_it())
```

I know this because the output is always the same:

```
0.1771815430790964
0.1771815430790964
0.1771815430790964
0.1771815430790964
0.1771815430790964
0.1771815430790964
0.1771815430790964
```

Comment: are you sure your threads are actually running concurrently? put some logging into them. Are you aware of the GIL and its implications for threaded code? miltiprocessing may work better.

Comment: what is the difference with multiprocessing?

Comment: please read my previous comment in full

Comment: How can I proof that they are running concurrently?

Comment: please read my previous comment in full - especially the bit about logging

Comment: I added the logging with a unique random number to the code

Comment: where is ThreadPool from?

Comment: from multiprocessing import Pool as ThreadPool

Comment: ok, see my answer. you need to read the multiprocessing docs and understand how the `map()` call works. plus see what I said above about the GIL and threading.

Comment: Thx for the hint with multi processing. If I have the process number equal to my processor number it is extremly fast.

Comment: So fast that even calling this website is slow because of the highly used bandwidth of the crawler :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this way it is running truely parallel. I experienced a significant speed up of the crawling. Awesome ;)

```
import multiprocessing
import random

def worker():
    """worker function"""

    x = random.random()*10
    x = round(x)
    while(True):
        print(x , ' Worker')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Comment: Lets says its running as multiple processes, truly parallel most likely not.

Comment: It does. From the docs: `Process objects represent activity that is run in a separate process`. You can verify by printing `os.getpid()` in each worker, and you'll see it does.

Comment: Don't forget to `join` your processes.

Comment: Because then you know all jobs are finished.

Answer (score 2):

you need to provide `pool.map()` an iterable

at the moment you're running `start_it()` which basically runs all your calls one after another. I don't know what implementation of `ThreadPool` you are using but you probably need to do something like:

```
pool.map(get_urls, list_of_urls)
```

Comment: I don't have a list of urls, because every get_urls() process takes a entry of a url database

Answer (score 0):

Not to digress, but Asynchronous IO is also a good candidate for your problem. You can use an amazing library called [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) which has been recently added to python 3.4. For older versions you can use [trollius](http://trollius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncio.html) or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted actualy runs, you shouldn't do `pool.map(start_it())`, as that calls `start_it` *before* passing the result to `pool.map`. Instead you must pass `start_it` without any `()`, as in `pool.map(start_it)`. You pprobably need another argument as well (values to pass to start_it).

You can try the example below, which seems to work for me.

```
import json
import multiprocessing.pool
import time
import urllib2

def run(no):
    for n in range(3):
        f = urllib2.urlopen("http://time.jsontest.com")
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        f.close()
        print("thread %d: %s" % (no, data))
        time.sleep(1)

pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(3)
pool.map(run, range(3))
```

You could also use `multiprocess.Process`, e.g.:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

def run(jobno):
    for n in range(3):
        print("job=%d pid=%d" % (jobno, os.getpid()))
        time.sleep(1)

jobs = []
for n in range(3):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=[n])
    jobs.append(p)

map(lambda x: x.start(), jobs)
map(lambda x: x.join(), jobs)
```

Example output:

```
job=0 pid=18347
job=1 pid=18348
job=2 pid=18349
job=0 pid=18347
job=2 pid=18349
job=1 pid=18348
job=2 pid=18349
job=0 pid=18347
job=1 pid=18348
```

Everything under the `multiprocessing` module uses *processes* instead of threads, which are truly parallel. Just note that there might be some issues with that (versus running them as threads under the same process).

Comment: Hi I edited my code and it works now. you see it below.